# Повлияет ли закрытие доступа к каталогу (Disallow: /images/) через robots.txt на индексацию изображений.

Tags: изображения, seo, индексация, robots.txt

К примеру есть ссылка site.ru/images/ данный адрес нужно запретить для поисковиков но в этом каталоге находятся изображения - повлияет ли это действие на индексацию в поисковиувх изображений находящихся в данном каталоге сайта(.../images/)?

Comment: Если робот хороший, то да. Если робот не следует правилам, то нет.

Comment: Робот яндекса, должен быть хорошим. Спасибо.

Comment: Яндекс следует правилам robots.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В целом, должно работать, но лучше подстраховаться.

Про картинки не знаю, но в Google порой попадают страницы, которые в `Disallow` прописаны, если на них кто-то ссылается.

Для веб страниц можно подстраховаться вставив в `head` секцию это:

```
<meta name="robots" content="no index, no follow" />
```

Answer (score 0):

В справке Гугл **[О файлах robots.txt](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=ru)**, сообщается:

> robots.txt – это специальный файл, расположенный в корневом каталоге сайта. Веб-мастер указывает в нем, ***какие страницы и данные не следует индексировать***.

Поэтому, скорее всего директива запрета на весь каталог в файле robots.txt исключит этот каталог из индексации. 
Однако, далее, в этой справке указано:

> Инструкции robots.txt носят рекомендательный характер.

Если вы желаете полностью исключить появление ваших картинок в поиске Гугл, то используйте **[Блокировка индексирования при помощи мета атрибута noindex](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710)**.

С этим же атрибутом, вы можете избрано запрещать индексацию для отдельных url.